# why android studio giving error when i remove null from function?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm new in android development. I'm using asynctask method for calling my function. Everything is working properly but i'm unable to know why function does return data and why android studio giving this error

```
> Error:(182, 9) error: missing return statement
```

When i remove `return null;`

here is code i hope you will understood what is my problem

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //Call getData function from here
            getData();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
            // do stuff after posting data
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938985/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-in-asynctasks-doinbackground-so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your method signature**

The method signature for your implementation of `doInBackground()` is as follows:

```
protected String doInBackground(String...strings)
```

Method signatures are broken down into access modifiers, return types, identifiers and parameters. The return type for your implementation `doInBackground()` is `String`.

**Android AsyncTask**

[Official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) states:

> An asynchronous task is defined by 3 generic types, called Params, Progress and Result

These are defined when you extend the AsyncTask class, as you have already done:

```
public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

The third parameter is your Result type, as you have specified here as `String`. This type is what must be returned by your implementation of `doInBackground()`

What this means is that your implementation of `doInBackGround()` *must* return a value of type `String`. Returning `null` is also acceptable (it is a valid value for any object data type). By removing `return null`, your method is not returning any value which is what produces the error message you are seeing.

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) may be helpful in understanding the structure of methods in Java.

Answer (score 1):

All functions with a `return` value defined in their signature must return something. This is different than in C/C++.

Here you declare your functions returns a `String`:

`protected` **`String`** `doInBackground(String... strings) {`

If you don't want to return anything, then you should change your method & class definition as follows:

```
        public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> { // <- Notice the change also here
        ...

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: If you want to bring C and C++ into this, I think it should be noted that not returning a value from a non-void function in c++ is undefined behaviour (except in the case of main)

Comment: Also note that specifying `Void` as the Result parameter still requires a `return statement`

Answer (score 0):

In your code :

```
YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

you extends AsyncTask which means :

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. Params : the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress : the type of the progress units published during the

   background computation.
3. Result : the type of the result of the
       background computation.

Now you declaring all type as a string you have to return string or null in 'doInBackground(String... strings)'

If you dont want to return anything then please use :

```
 public class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using `Void` as a return value still requires `return null;`. In fact, returning anything else would be an error. But you're correct, this is what should be used if there's no need for a return value.